# XML: Return Text Value?

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, lxml

I'm using XML to return the text values for the values below.  I'm using the absolute path to map to the location of the text value.  I'm fairly confident the path is accurate.  However, when I try to return the value I'm not returning value.   Do does anyone see errors in the code that might prevent the value from returning the text value?

```
import requests
from lxml import html


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.marketwatch.com'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text

parser = html.fromstring(response)


r_name = parser.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul[2]/li[1]/div[3]/div/p/text()')
print(r_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath looks correct to me, given the content in that web page. `lxml`'s XPath parser is known to be often buggy identifying elements with index, however. You can search by attribute instead:

```
r_name = parser.xpath('//p[@class="article__summary"]/text()')
```